# how to found top 20 visited items to add them ad favorites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Im Using core data.
in that i was worked on recently visited items as follows.

```
//Create a fetch request
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Recent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

//set Predicate to the fetch request
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eyeTerm = %@",term];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;

//Create an Array Using fetch Request
NSMutableArray *recentsArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
if([recentsArray count]==0) {
    //Save to Recent
    Recent *recent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    recent.eyeTerm=term;
    recent.lastviewed = [NSDate date];
    recent.repeatCount = 0;
}

else {
    //Increment the repeatCount of the recent object.
    Recent *recent = [recentsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    int countValue = [recent.repeatCount intValue];
    countValue ++;
    recent.repeatCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:countValue];
    NSLog(@"repeat count : %@",recent.repeatCount );
}
```

Now i want top 20 visited tiems (repeat count).
and then i can add them as favorites.
please tell me how to found top 20.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByRepeats = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"repeatCount" ascending:NO];
```

Then you can use that when you create your fetch request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];   NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription                                   entityForName:@"Recent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];   
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:20];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByRepeats]];
```